# Where can I find the official Duty Free allowances for New Caledonia?

Tags: duty-free, new-caledonia

I've tried searching for the Duty Free allowances for New Caledonia, but all I can seem to find are forum posts and summary information on duty free or airport websites. Some of these seem to conflict, so I'd really like to find the official rules on it, rather than rely on third party information.

Where can I find the official Duty Free allowances and rules for New Caledonia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about 30 minutes of searching, I've finally tracked it down! Possibly someone in the NC government needs to spend some time on the [Webmasters SE site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) ;-)

The official details are available on [douane.gouv.nc](http://www.douane.gouv.nc/portal/page/portal/douane/particuliers/voyageurs) and are:

> 2 litres de vins tranquilles ET 1 litre de boisson titrant plus de 22°
>
> OU
>
> 2 litres de boissons titrant 22° ou moins

Which in English is either:

- 2 litres of still wine *and* 1 litre of spirits of more than 22%
- or 2 litres of spirits of 22% or less